# Swiper API - How to get alert on swipe for left side?

Tags: jquery, html, browser, swiper.js

I´m using Swiper API on my aplication. I would like to know, how do I get the side of user is browsing. I have read the documentation on (http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VgFind9VhBc), but not found the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example:

```
swiper.on( 'slideChange', function() {
   if ( swiper.activeIndex > swiper.previousIndex ) {
       alert( 'left' );
   } else {
       alert( 'right' );
   }
});
```

The Swiper object has the index and another infos inside. You do not need an event.

Try to look at the object:

```
console.log(swiper);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
galleryExample.on('slideChangeStart',function(event){
               if(event.activeIndex > event.previousIndex){
                   alert('left');
               }else{
                   alert('right');
               }
            });
```

event.activeIndex is the active item of slider and event.previousIndex is index of item you slider was on before.